# How to scope all queries on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with spree on rails 3.1.10.

I want to scope all the queries on a model, `Variants` such that only the variants with `deleted_at` column are returned. I want to put this condition on all queries like, `find_by_%`, `where` etc.

How can I achieve this? The variant class in the spree core already has the following:

```
include ::Scopes::Variant
  # default variant scope only lists non-deleted variants
  scope :active, where("variants.deleted_at is null")
  scope :deleted, where("not variants.deleted_at is null")
```

Not sure why the queries in the console are not according to this scope

So, 1. How can I scope all queries
    2. Why is the default scope in the spree-core not being applied, do I need to include this in my decorator also?

Answer (score 0):

For 1 - use a [default_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope) for the model to scope all queries

```
default_scope where("variants.deleted_at is null")
```

Comment: This gives an error while accessing the orders containing the deleted variant

Answer (score -1):

You need to use default_scope.
My advice: 
you need to create child model

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class AWithDeletedIsNull(or another) < A
  default_scope where("variants.deleted_at is null")
end

class AWithDeletedIsNotNull(or another) < A
  default_scope where("not variants.deleted_at is null")
end
```

To Use:

```
VariantWithDeletedIsNull.find(1)
```